# Is there an ergonomic way to start a rebase after a `git bisect`?

Tags: git

When doing exploratory works, especially GUI, I often create many commits before merging them into master (so I can safely rebase them). I often find bugs in those and use git bisect to identify the root cause. Since bisect knows on what branch I am currently, is there a way to create a commit/amend the last one, then immediately start a rebase of the branch I was on.

Currently, I do the needed modifications, stash them, copy the hash of the faulty commit, `git bisect reset` immediately followed by a `git rebase --interactive $hash~`, mark the commit for edit, `git stash pop && git add -u && git rebase --continue`. It works, but is there a more ergonomic way to do the same. Something like an hypothetical `git bisect rebase --amend`?

Comment: There isn't—but you could easily write a *script* to do this. Use `git rev-parse` to save the current hash ID, use `git bisect reset` to return to the desired branch, and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current workflow might look like:

```bash
+----------------------+        +-----------------+        +-----------------+
| git bisect           |  --->  | Modify & Stash  |  --->  | Copy Faulty Hash |
+----------------------+        +-----------------+        +-----------------+
       |                                                            |
       v                                                            v
+-------------------+       +--------------------------+       +----------------------+
| git bisect reset  |  ---> | git rebase --interactive |  ---> | Edit, Stash Pop, Add |
+-------------------+       +--------------------------+       +----------------------+
                                                                    |
                                                                    v
                                                               +-----------------------+
                                                               | git rebase --continue |
                                                               +-----------------------+
```

That current process for rebasing after a `git bisect` involves several steps, which can be a bit cumbersome.
While there is no direct `git bisect rebase --amend` command, you could streamline the process with a custom script or Git alias.

Create a git alias or script: that script or alias will combine the steps of resetting the bisect, starting an interactive rebase, and preparing the commit for amendment.

Automate stash operations and commit amendment: the script can automatically apply the stashed changes and amend the commit without needing manual intervention.

For instance, a `git-bisect-rebase.sh` script would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: git-bisect-rebase.sh

# Get the current bisecting commit
current_bisect_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# Reset the bisect to get back to the original branch
git bisect reset

# Start an interactive rebase
git rebase --interactive "$current_bisect_commit~" --autosquash

# The script assumes that you will manually resolve conflicts and continue the rebase
```

Note: this script is a starting point that can be improved. For example, it could automatically pop the stash if you always stash your changes before running this script.

---

Also, if you ever `git bisect` during a *rebase* in progress, note that Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) will show the correct branch name in "`git status`" output.

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cce4778520b6ade4bc839fe054500253f7d22570/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> is taught to show both the branch being bisected and being rebased when both are in effect at the same time.

See [commit 990adcc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/990adccbdf0d8d1056c49a5ed546e744f542ba8f) (09 Sep 2023) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cce4778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cce4778520b6ade4bc839fe054500253f7d22570), 02 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`status`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/990adccbdf0d8d1056c49a5ed546e744f542ba8f): fix branch shown when not only bisecting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> In [83c750a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83c750acde6ac5847845f9c2eeb3261cf9cc54bc) ("`wt-status.*`: better advice for [`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/83c750acde6ac5847845f9c2eeb3261cf9cc54bc/Documentation/git-status.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> added", 2012-06-05, Git v1.7.12-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30e8e6fdeadbd7c3f7dd8defed654e1e98290a45) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7b44f182bc1b2ac32eadbc477a76a185f49ac88)), `git-status` received new informative messages to describe the ongoing work in a worktree.
>
> These messages were enhanced in [0722c80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0722c805d616eb644a868a995b891470f9e5e30d) ("`status`: show the branch name if possible in in-progress info", 2013-02-03, Git v1.8.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55f9c8351d8bf0aca18cb3472ec081ad57c96543)), to show, if possible, the branch where the operation was initiated.
>
> Since then, we show incorrect information when several operations are in progress and one of them is bisect:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b foo
> $ GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='echo break >' git rebase -i HEAD~
> $ git checkout -b bar
> $ git bisect start
> $ git status
> ...
>
> You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'bar' on '...'.
>
> You are currently bisecting, started from branch 'bar'.
>
> ...
> ```
>
> Note that we erroneously say "while rebasing branch 'bar'" when we should be referring to "foo".
>
> That must have gone unnoticed for so long because it must be unusual to start a bisection while another operation is in progress.
> And even less usual to involve different branches.
>
> It caught my attention reviewing a leak introduced in [8b87cfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b87cfd000c7c98f58279cff698f6e8c7892c059) ("`wt-status`: move strbuf into `read_and_strip_branch()`", 2013-03-16, Git v1.8.3-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc2e81247042e11d9cf981ac5671746caddc22a)).
>
> A simple change to deal with this situation can be to record in struct `wt_status_state,` the branch where the bisect starts separately from the branch related to other operations.
>
> Let's do it and so we will be able to display correct information and we will avoid the leak as well.